# Scoring for loans

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a python class called Score, I intend to use it to assign scores depending on 2 parameters, first the type of score - score name and second the user_input, so for example if I want to get the score of loan term, I will enter 'loan_term' as the first parameter and loan term value 36 as the second parameter; a function in the class then calculates the score and returns the value.

The idea is to be able to re-use this class as and when needed and to be able to modify the code outside of the main application code.

So I will like someone to review this class implementation and let me know if I have deviated from known standards or is there a better way to implement this?

```
class Score:
    def __init__(self, score_name):
        self.score_name = score_name

    def get_score_name(self):
        return self.score_name

    def get_score(get_score_name, user_input):
        # loan term score grading
        if get_score_name == 'loan_term' and user_input <= 18:
            i = 5
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_term' and user_input <= 24:
            i = 4
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_term' and user_input <= 48:
            i = 3
        # loan reason score grading
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 0:
            i = 3.5
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 1:
            i = 2.0
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 2:
            i = 1.5
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 3:
            i = 2.5
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 4:
            i = 1.5
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 5:
            i = 2.0
        elif get_score_name == 'loan_reason' and user_input == 6:
            i = 0.5
        # job security score grading
        elif get_score_name == 'job_security' and user_input == 0:
            i = 1.0
        elif get_score_name == 'job_security' and user_input == 1:
            i = 2.0
        elif get_score_name == 'job_security' and user_input == 2:
            i = 3.0
        elif get_score_name == 'job_security' and user_input == 3:
            i = 4.0
        elif get_score_name == 'job_security' and user_input == 4:
            i = 5.0
        # average apr score grading
        elif get_score_name == 'average_apr' and user_input <= -1.0:
            i = 5
        elif get_score_name == 'average_apr' and user_input <= -0.6:
            i = 4
        elif get_score_name == 'average_apr' and user_input < 0.5:
            i = 3
        elif get_score_name == 'average_apr' and user_input <= 1.0:
            i = 2
        elif get_score_name == 'average_apr' and user_input > 1.0:
            i = 1
        # monthly expenses score grading
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input < 0.10:
            i = 5
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input < 0.20:
            i = 4
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input < 0.30:
            i = 3
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input < 0.40:
            i = 1
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input > 0.40:
            i = 0
        # monthly surplus score grading
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_surplus' and user_input < 0.20:
            i = 5
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_surplus' and user_input < 0.35:
            i = 4
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_surplus' and user_input < 0.45:
            i = 3
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_surplus' and user_input <= 0.60:
            i = 2
        elif get_score_name == 'monthly_surplus' and user_input > 0.60:
            i = 1
        else:
            i = 0

        return i

# # loan term test

# loan_term_score = Score.get_score(Score('loan_term').get_score_name(), 21)
# print(f'loan term  score: {loan_term_score}')


# # loan reason test

# loan_reason_score = Score.get_score(Score('loan_reason').get_score_name(), 2)
# print(f'loan reason score: {loan_reason_score}')

# # job security test

# job_security_score = Score.get_score(Score('job_security').get_score_name(), 3)
# print(f'job security score: {job_security_score}')


# # average apr test

# average_apr_score = Score.get_score(Score('average_apr').get_score_name(), 1.0)
# print(f'average apr score: {average_apr_score}')

# # monthly expenses test

# monthly_expenses_score = Score.get_score(Score('monthly_expenses').get_score_name(), 0.15)
# print(f'monthly expenses score: {monthly_expenses_score}')

# # monthly surplus test

# monthly_surplus_score = Score.get_score(Score('monthly_surplus').get_score_name(), 0.55)
# print(f'monthly surplus score: {monthly_surplus_score}')
```

Comment: Welcome to code review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Bug

```
    elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input < 0.40:
        i = 1
    elif get_score_name == 'monthly_expenses' and user_input > 0.40:
        i = 0
```

What happens if `user_input` is exactly 4.0?

### General algorithm

Those sequential `if`s should go away. Maintain a dictionary where the key is a score name and the value is a sorted tuple of 2-tuples: input threshold and score. Look up the outer tuple by score name, then use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to do efficient lookup of the applicable score.

### Score name

`get_score_name` as a method name is fine. `get_score_name` as a parameter name is confusing and should simply be `score_name`, though that parameter should not even exist since you already have `self.score_name`.

### Example code

Note:

- I've taken liberties with some of your boundary conditions that didn't make sense; in particular the upper boundary for `monthly_surplus`
- This approach allows for some slightly silly things to happen, like `loan_reason` and `job_security` coercing floating-point answers to integers, when - for these two categories - floating-point doesn't make sense
- `user_input` is put in a tuple for easy comparison to the other threshold tuples

```
from bisect import bisect
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Optional

ScoreName = str
Score = float
Threshold = float
ScorePair = Tuple[Threshold, Score]
ScoreDict = Dict[ScoreName, Tuple[ScorePair, ...]]

INF = float('inf')

THRESHOLDS: ScoreDict = {
    'loan_term': (
        (18, 5),
        (24, 4),
        (48, 3),
    ),
    'loan_reason': (
        (0, 3.5),
        (1, 2.0),
        (2, 1.5),
        (3, 2.5),
        (4, 1.5),
        (5, 2.0),
        (6, 0.5),
    ),
    'job_security': (
        (0, 1),
        (1, 2),
        (2, 3),
        (3, 4),
        (4, 5),
    ),
    'average_apr': (
        (-1.0, 5),
        (-0.6, 4),
        ( 0.5, 3),
        ( 1.0, 2),
        ( INF, 1),
    ),
    'monthly_expenses': (
        (0.1, 5),
        (0.2, 4),
        (0.3, 3),
        (0.4, 1),
        (INF, 0),
    ),
    'monthly_surplus': (
        (0.20, 5),
        (0.35, 4),
        (0.45, 3),
        (0.60, 2),
        ( INF, 1),
    ),
}


def get_score(score_name: ScoreName, user_input: Threshold) -> Optional[Score]:
    thresholds = THRESHOLDS[score_name]
    index = bisect(thresholds, (user_input,))
    if index >= len(thresholds):
        return None
    return thresholds[index][1]


def test():
    assert get_score('loan_term', 17) == 5
    assert get_score('loan_term', 18) == 5
    assert get_score('loan_term', 48) == 3
    assert get_score('loan_term', 49) is None
    assert get_score('monthly_surplus', 0.62) == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```